# Store URL parts on click and build url on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Did a search and usually find what I want but didn't have any luck finding this which is why I question if this can be done.

With one of our companies CMS we are very limited with what we control and the external (owners of the CMS) team that we should be relying on to develop the CMS, build tools, plugins etc are just too slow that we could be waiting 6-12 months for developments.

So one of the things we want to do is store parts of a url when you click a button in step 1, then step 2, step 3 etc. then on a final click submit and build a url structure from the choices selected in each step.

So for example a customer would click the **Clothing** button in Step 1, then **T-Shirts** button in step 2, then **adidas** button in step 3 and then finally you click a **See the products** button and submit your selection which would take you to the url

> /clothing/t-shirts/adidas

(our category page structure). Also just to add to this is it possible so in step 3 you can select multiple options before submitting so if you select 3 buttons it would build the URL

> /clothing/t-shirts/adidas+boss+cp-company

etc?

Is this possible with jQuery and any help on achieving it?

Comment: 1: Yes it is possible 2. We help those who show code as in [mcve] :)

Comment: are these steps on separate pages, or all in one page? If the latter, just keep a JS variable containing the proposed URL, and update that variable after each step. jQuery is not necessarily required to do this, although it might make the syntax nicer. Have you tried anything yet? The concept is not so different from maintaining the state of any variable in your code

Answer (score 0):

It's not jQuery, but this might help you:

```
function addToURL(item){
    history.replaceState(history.state, "", location.href.split('?')[0] + "/" + item);
}
```

Be aware though that if user refreshes the page when the URL is modified, it will go to that URL instead of refreshing the original page, so if `/t-shirts/` is not a valid link, they might end up on a 404 page.

Comment: jQuery is not a language

Comment: I know. Still doesn't change the fact that this solution is not using jQuery whereas the OP asked for a solution "with jQuery" ;)

Comment: I know. Asking for jquery solutions just bugs me. :)